# Responsive height for a form in a card when resizing a textarea

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

I'm currently working on my first website and I am coding a form in a card (I'll show the css of the card). My problem is when I try to resize the textarea, it goes beyond the borders of the card and it also moves the button "Send" out of the card. And on top of that the section's height isn't resized but there is a scroll bar that appears on the right side.

Here is the html :

```
<section class="form">
        <div class="container grid">
          <div class="show" data-aos="fade-right">
            <img src="images/polytech.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="card">
              <p>N'hésitez pas à nous contacter pour toute demande de devis.</p>
              <h1>Contactez nous</h1>
              <p>Email : contact@linkopg.onmicrosoft.com</p>
              <p>Téléphone : 06 79 24 06 79 </p>
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/linko-polytech-grenoble/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x"></i></a>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/linko.polytech/"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/linko_polytech_grenoble/"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="showcase-form card" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <form action="">
              <div class="form-control container grid">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nom" required />
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Prénom" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-control">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="company"
                  placeholder="Entreprise"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-control">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre Email" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Votre numéro de téléphone" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-control" aria-invalid="false">
                <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Votre message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="btn btn-secondary "/>
              <div id="status"></div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS :

```
.container.grid {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.card {
    background-color: white;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;  
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;

}
.form {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.form h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form p {
    line-height:1.1em;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.showcase-form.card {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: inherit;
}

.form img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.form a {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

.form i:hover {
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.form .grid {
    overflow: visible;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    gap:  20px;
    padding: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.form-control.grid {
    overflow: visible;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    gap:  10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
}

.showcase {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.showcase h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.showcase p {
    line-height:1.1em;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 40px;

}

.showcase .grid {
    overflow: visible;
    grid-template-columns: 55% 45%;
    gap: 30 px;
}


.showcase-form .form-control {
    margin: 30px 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.showcase-form input {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b4becb;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}


textarea{
    padding: 10px;
    resize: vertical;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.showcase-form input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Here are the images :

[Form before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFGtv.png)
[Form after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9ggu.png)

[form after resizing 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTh2z.png)

Comment: please provide a stackblitz so I can debug.

Comment: textarea has a fixed height

Comment: Do you want to resize the card with the textarea or you wanted to stop the textarea from resizing

Comment: @GahanVig I want to resize the card with the textarea and if possible I want to remove the scroll bar that appears on the right when resizing the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the height property from `.showcase-form` class -

```css
.showcase-form.card {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: inherit;
}
```

or set the height property to `fit-content` -

```css
.showcase-form.card {
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: It actually worked, it resizes the card when resizing the text area. But I still have the problem with the scrollbar appearing on the right when I resize it. The second image shows it.

Comment: If the content will go out of the window it will obviously show a scroll bar

Comment: I've added an image to show it, so it is normal then ?

Comment: @TiavRANDRIA I have exactly copied the code and run it on PC but It is not showing any scrollbar. I You should try running your site on another browser or reload and remove cache from your browser by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + R`

Comment: I solved it, I had the elemen section with a fixed height of 100vh. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I am glad to help you